# How to avoid this loop in R?

Tags: r

I'm computing "haversine distances" (distances using latlong) for each row I have in a data set. I need to compute distance for each observation from "place X" to "place Y".

I would love to avoid running a loop for each row because it's too slow. How could I improve the code or avoid the loop?

The code I runned is the following:

```
#--> creating a variable to fill each row  with haversine distances

test$haverdi <- c('inputhaverdist') 

#--> for each row, lets compute haver distance using placeXlongt(column 3) 
#--> placeXlong (column 4)  (origin ) and placeYlong(column 10 ), 
#--> placeYlat(column  11) (destination). 


for (i in 1:nrow(test)){

   test[i,ncol(test)] <- as.numeric(distHaversine(c(test[i,3],test[i,4] ), c(test[i,10],test[i,11])))                                   
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `distHaversine` is vectorized. Try `test$havrdi = distHaversine(test[, 3:4], test[, 10:11])`.

Comment: As an FYI, you shouldn't initialize a column as text if you want it to be a number. Rather than `test$haverdi <- c('inputhaverdist')`, if you did need to loop a better start would be `test$haverdi <- NA`. I assume you added the `as.numeric()` because things were coming up as `character`, but they only came out character because of your `c('inputhaverdist')` line.

Comment: @Gregor Also, 1) `c('inputhaverdist')` is a frequent silly way of assigning **just one** value to something. It outputs the  same as `'inputhaverdist'` without the unnecessary function call. 2) The bars /// are not the comment char.

Comment: @Gregor
Yes, it was vectorized, thanks!.  I don't know why I couldn't calculate it before.
Oh, yes you were right, a better way would be with  test[,i] <- NA.
Thanks for  all the help!

Comment: @RuiBarradas yeah, I did that because I couldn't comment with # without changing the size of the text.

Thank you!